# What do you call the tail of the email?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, email

When I hit "reply" to an email message, unless I edit it out, the message I am replying to is contained in the new message.  After some back and forth, a long "tail" accumulates.  I am preparing an archive of email correspondence.  I need to explain that I removed signatures and "tails."  I don't know how to explain this thing I call a "tail."  In my draft I am calling it "prior messages," which doesn't seem terribly clear.  Is there a term for this?  Or can you help me make one up that will be self-explanatory?

> The enclosed archive of email correspondence includes all messages and headers but no **prior messages** or signatures.

Comment: Is it a *chain*? Possibly *thread*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, that’s what I’d call it.

Comment: Some messaging systems call these ***conversations***.

Comment: It’s not a thread—the thread consists of all the individual e-mails that make up the entire conversation, including the one currently being archived. The ‘tail’ is included in each and every e-mail and consists of a reverse-order ***quoting*** of all previous messages in the fork of the thread that the current e-mail is located in. You might get away with calling it something like **nested quotes**.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But wouldn’t find anything wrong with an an email that said, “Don’t bother reading all the previous emails, the whole [chain, thread] is included here.” Granted, that’s more of a semantic interpretation...

Comment: @Jim True, in that context it works, but I think that's because it sets the current e-mail up as being outside the actual conversation—the thread then becomes a quote, rather than the current conversation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Could we see this in an answer, please?  Very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The enclosed archive of email correspondence includes all messages and headers, though  **quoted text from previous messages** has been deleted for brevity.*

This phrase, in bold font above, is copied from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style

> When a message is replied to in e-mail, Internet forums, or Usenet, the original can often be included, or "quoted", in a variety of different posting styles.
>
> The main options are interleaved posting (also called inline replying, in which the different parts of the reply follow the relevant parts of the original post), bottom-posting (in which the reply follows the quote) or top-posting (in which the reply precedes the quoted original message). For each of those options, there is also the issue of whether trimming of the original text is allowed, required or preferred.
> [...]
> **Quoted text from previous messages** is usually distinguished in some way from the new (reply) text. [...]

On a side note, trimming such text seems very error prone, especially if there have been *interleaved or bottom replies*. It could
also  be misleading if emails are presented
out of context and order.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph -- all the messages, without exception, were top-posted, and I used a thunderbird tool called ImportExportTools to make the archive of all the messages in a folder (which was created with a "label" in gmail).  This tool automatically sorts the messages by date.  Your comment has given me the idea of adding to my explanation the fact that all the messages were top-posted.  (I already noted that the archive contains a complete set -- although your last paragraph is giving me the idea to put more emphasis on that.)

Comment: I like the phrase in bold that you found, and I also like the verb *trim*.

Answer (score 2):

I use *email exchange* to describe the newest message plus the long tail that has accumulated. If you apply that to your example, you could say:

> The enclosed archive of email correspondence includes only the newest
>   messages and headers from each *email exchange*.
>
> OR
>
> The enclosed archive of *email exchanges* includes only the newest
>   messages and headers from each *email exchange*.

Comment: It's really clear.  I'll use this as a back-up.  I'd prefer to say what I'm omitting (or not including), if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As Janus mentions in his comment, the **tail** you refer to is the result of the e-mail client automatically quoting what you're replying to. Therefore, I think the noun you're looking for **quotations**.

This is how I'd write your sentence:

> The enclosed archive of email correspondence includes all messages and headers, with automatic **quotations** and overly long signatures removed for the sake of clarity and brevity.

The *automatic* bit I have added because I assume you haven't deleted any in-line quotations that some people use when addressing multiple points discussed in previous e-mails.

Comment: I won't be able to use it because in the same paragraph I talk about quotations from something else, so it would be confusing.  But I bet someone will be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The enclosed archive contains all the email messages I sent to or received from XX.  Signatures and **redundant quotes** have been omitted for readability.

"Redundant quotes" is redundant, I know, but I thought it would make things clearer.